# Clustering with multiple measures over time

Tags: r, clustering, discriminant-analysis

I have a little issue with my data, I am not sure how i can reach my objective. I apologize already if it is a dummy question.

I have around 200 insects, monitored individually, of 3 different species (determined on morphological features of the last instar, and on adult when possible). After each molt, we measured different parameters (among others the total length, the head width...). When we visualize the plot of the total length vs the head width, we can see the 3 species exhibit 3 different patterns (1 color= 1species):

[image]

What I am looking for is a clustering method, or any other method who could discriminate the 3 species based on their measurements and growth patterns. until now, i didn't find the right method to take into consideration that a same individual is measured at different time (and, of course, stay the same species over time).

Any advice or solution?

thank you very much for your help!

PS: I work with R, if a package is necessary

Comment: Given the mixture of discrete and continuous features in your data, a latent class mixture model could work. Several threads discuss this approach, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112101/latent-class-models which addresses issues related to growth but there are many more CV threads worth poking through.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to consider the measurements after each molt as separate features.

So, for each insect you would have a vector like:

$$ [head_{molt1}, length_{molt1}, head_{molt2}, length_{molt2}, ...] $$

You can also add the number of days between molts, and maybe some more data.

Then you can use any standard clustering/classification algorithm.

The problem with this is that it assumes that each insect has the same number of molts, which is unlikely, I suppose.
How to fix this?
The simplest approach would be to use the minimum number of molts that each insect has. For those insects with more molts, you simple discard the latest molts.
Another approach would be to use the average number of molts. If an insect has fewer molts, you have some missing data, that you could fix using the average value for that feature, for example. Or infer the value with linear regression.

By the way, if you want an algorithm to distinguish the 3 species, a supervised algorithm will very likely perform better than any clustering method, which are unsupervised. One of the simplest would be logistic regression, which will also tell you which features are important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I would consider this to be three different patterns...

But by any means, you need to **improve your features**.

On one hand the *ratio* of the two variables is probably more interesting, and on the other hand size / time, as there clearly seems to be a *third* variable causing this correlation.